# What is an End of The World (ETW) brane?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, branes

In literature I have found this terminology several times and I would like to see if there is a definition of the 'end of the world' brane. [This](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.06667) paper is the closest thing I could find to a definition. Here the end of the world brane is what we replace with the left hand side of a two-sided wormhole. It is associated to the black hole which is dual to a highly excited CFT at the boundary(using AdS/CFT correspondence).

I might be wrong but should we think of this as a state which is in the black hole?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.14376